# Require jQuery cookie to store new value as an element

Tags: jquery, cookies

Can I append new value as a jQuery syntax to jQuery cookie?

Set cookie:

```
$('#set').click(function () {
   $.cookie('p', '$(<"p">).text("Hello World!").css("color", "red")') 
});
```

Get cookie:

```
$('#get').click(function () {
   $('body').append($.cookie('p'))
});
```

I'd tried, it showed me a plain text instead of an element. Like this:

> $(<"p">).text("Hello World!").css("color", "red")

Or: *Is there a way to try to convert a plain text to jQuery syntax?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are settings jQuery **code** to a cookie as a **string**.
When you try to append it, it is appended as a string, obviously.

If you want to store the element, you can store it as an HTML:

```
$('#set').click(function () {
    $.cookie('p', $("<p/>").text("Hello World!").css("color", "red").html());
});

$('#get').click(function () {
    $('body').append($.cookie('p'))
});
```

Comment: Sorry. But Google Chrome threw error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in line `$.cookie('p', $(<"p">).text("Hello World!").css("color", "red").html());`

Comment: Thanks. It's working without: creating `<p>` tag and appending css color :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove `<>` across the `"p"` and write `"<p>"`

**Set cookie:**

```
$('#set').click(function () {
   $.cookie('p', '$("<p>").text("Hello World!").css("color", "red")') 
});
```

**Get cookie:**

```
$('#get').click(function () {
   $('body').append($($.cookie('p')));
});
```

Convert it again to `jQuery` object using `$($.cookie('p'))`

Comment: Error: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $("p").text("Hello World!").css("color", "red")`

Comment: I'm so sorry to say this, but it's still not working with same error.